# All value parameter in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, function

I have built a function to query data. I currently want to add another parameter to my function.

When the parameter is "ALL" it should display all data, else only the data that was queried.

```
if (p_agent = 'ALL') then
```

The above is what I have so far, I'm not sure what to do next to specify the ELSE statement. I am dealing with varchar/strings for that parameter.

the parameter is linked to this column:

```
bor.also_known_as
```

Link to CODE:
http://pastebin.com/h16BByfj

Thanks in advance

Comment: [edit] your question and add the complete code of the function

Comment: You can use something like `where (table_field = p_agent or p_agent = 'ALL')`